# Function not being invoked when the 'dispatch' keyword is present

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I have this method:

```
export const logout = replace => async dispatch => {
    Alert.alert(
        "Logout",
        "Are you sure?",
        [{
                text: "No",
                style: "cancel"
            },
            {
                text: "OK",
                onPress: () => logoutUser()
            }
        ], {
            cancelable: false
        }
    );
};
```

And it doesn't get called when the `dispatch` keyword is there. Not sure what's going on, because my store seems to be properly configured (I've tested that by adding data to my state and console logging it).

```
import {
    createStore,
    applyMiddleware
} from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";

import rootReducer from "./reducers";

const middleware = [thunk];

const initialState = {};

const configureStore = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    initialState,
    applyMiddleware(...middleware)
);

export default configureStore;
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

---

Edit:

Whole `logout` method:

```
export const logout = replace => {
    console.log("entered?"); // never prints

    const logoutUser = async () => {
        dispatch({
            type: LOGOUT
        });

        await SecureStore.deleteItemAsync("jwt");

        replace("Home", {
            name: "Home"
        });
    };

    Alert.alert(
        "Logout",
        "Are you sure?",
        [{
                text: "No",
                style: "cancel"
            },
            {
                text: "OK",
                onPress: () => logoutUser()
            }
        ], {
            cancelable: false
        }
    );
};
```

Comment: try ``dispatchEvent`` instead of ``dispatch``.

Comment: Still doesn't work

Comment: Where is the 'replace' variable used?

Comment: @hongdevelop I've updated the question. I'm using react navigation, but the problem is that even `entered?` is never printed. It is printed when I get rid of `dispatch` keyword

Answer (score 0):

```js
const logoutUser = () => dispatch => {
        dispatch({
            type: LOGOUT
        });


        replace("Home", {
            name: "Home"
        });
    };
```

Comment: I have the line `import { CHECK_AUTH, AUTH_SUCCESS, AUTH_ERROR, LOGOUT } from "./types";` at the top. It would throw an error 'undefined variable LOGOUT' if I didn't import it

Comment: What does the logout action do?

Comment: I've tried, but still nothing. The logout method deletes token from SecureStorage (async) and then replaces view with Home screen. That's one of the main reasons why it should be `const logoutUser = () => async dispatch => {` instead of `const logoutUser = async () => dispatch => {`

Comment: So what does the logout action do? Is there a reason to do it when there's nothing?

Comment: I've updated the question above. The logout action does `await SecureStore.deleteItemAsync("jwt"));`. Other components do `await SecureStore.getItemAsync("jwt"));` and if token exists, render component. If token doesn't exist, display Home

Comment: If you are already deleting the save from the action, you are deleting it twice. Please correct it like my answer.

Comment: I've figured it out and posted my answer. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I figured it out (kinda). Hacky approach, but hey, that's programming.

Anyway, I was trying to access `logout` from `navigationOptions`, which itself was an exported method, not "connected" to the app. Anyway, I dropped the `=> async dispatch {` and imported the store from `/src/store` and did the following:

```
import store from "../store";

export const logout = async replace => {
    await SecureStore.deleteItemAsync("jwt");

    store.dispatch({
        type: LOGOUT
    });

    replace("Home", {
        name: "Home"
    });
};
```